# Add entry to dictionary in child object

Tags: spring, configuration, configuration-files, spring.net

How is it possible to **add** entry to dictionary, defined in parent object, from the child object?

***UPDATED**
I edit my config as follows:

```
<object id="ParentType" singleton="false" type="SomeType">
  <property name="FieldNameMap">
   <dictionary key-type="string"  value-type="string" >
     <entry key="Title" value="TitleName"/>     
    </dictionary>
  </property>
</object>

<object id="ChildType" singleton="false" type="SomeType" parent="ParentType">
  <property name="FieldNameMap">
   <dictionary merge="true">
     <!-- this entry should be added to, not replace the whole Dictionary -->
     <entry key="Position" value="PositionName"/>     
    </dictionary>
  </property>
</object>
```

but, unfortunately, it now throws cast exception:

> Cannot convert property value of type
>   [System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary] to required type
>   [System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String,
>   ],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

Comment: I have tried specifing `key-type` and `value-type` in the child dictionary with the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but [according to the docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-collections-values), spring.net will use the `Add` method of the collection to add items, if the collection itself is exposed as a readonly property.

So it might be possible to use [object definition inheritance](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-childobjects) to achieve the behavior you describe. Config will be something like:

```
<object id="ParentType" singleton="false" type="SomeType"
        abstract="true">
  <property name="FieldNameMap">
   <dictionary>
     <entry key="Title" value="TitleName"/>     
    </dictionary>
  </property>
</object>

<object id="ChildType" singleton="false" type="SomeType" 
        parent="ParentType">
  <property name="FieldNameMap">
   <dictionary>
     <!-- this entry should be added to, not replace the whole Dictionary -->
     <entry key="Position" value="PositionName"/>     
    </dictionary>
  </property>
</object>
```

This will only work if `FieldNameMap` is a readonly property.

Comment: Correct, even better(with Spring 1.3+): you can now merge non-readonly list, dictionary, name-values and set collections(see 5.3.2.6. Collection Merging).

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't work as expected, please, see updated Q

Comment: Fixed issue, created pull request: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/pull/52

Comment: The child object definition in you question does not reference the parent; have you tried `<object id="ChildType" singleton="false" type="SomeType" ___ parent="ParentType" ___ >`.

Comment: sorry for that, its a typo in Q. Corrected.